# Ruby on Rails content security policy (CSP) nonce not allowing jQuery replaceWith

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

I'm working on a legacy site with a good amount of inline javascript. We recently had a pen-test done and it told us our CSP was implemented insecurely. There's too much inline javascript for me to convert all at once so for the short term I figured I'd use nonces to provide a little more security. However it seems like a lot of javascript is now failing on this block

```js
 var PageRenderer = class extends Renderer {
    static renderElement(currentElement, newElement) {
      if (document.body && newElement instanceof HTMLBodyElement) {
        // Fails here on replaceWith
        document.body.replaceWith(newElement);
      } else {
        document.documentElement.appendChild(newElement);
      }
    }
```

Looking around I found this jQuery issue from several years ago that says the nonce value wasn't being passed through, however it also looks like it was fixed already?

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3541

here's the script_src from our CSP and we are on jQuery 3.6.1, Rails 7.0.4, Ruby 3.1.2. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```rb
policy.script_src  :self, :https, 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net', 'https://cdn.plaid.com', :blob, 'http://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js', 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js'
```

Comment: The JS code here doesn't even use jQuery or even seem to have anything to do with it - are you sure you're not chasing a red herring?

Comment: @max you might be right, I was grinding against it all day yesterday but now looking at it with fresh eyes it looks like it might be running up against an inline event handler

Comment: [Element.replaceWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceWith) is a native function supported by all modern browsers. What is the actual error?